# Как сделать график Chartjs посередине экрана

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Я использую vue-chartjs и мне нужно чтобы мой график при маунте приложения был не от начала до конца полотна, а немного не доходил до конца. Пока я это могу сделать при помощи плагина zoom для chartjs но только вручную. Вот что я имею сейчас при загрузке графика[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что мне нужно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]